# How to solve this integral (complex variables - green's function)

Tags: complex-integration, residue-calculus, greens-function

I am trying to resolve the following EDP
$$(\nabla^2+m^2)f(x,y,z)=g(x,y,z),$$
where $m$ is a constant (very small).

For that, I'm using Green's Method of Functions. In developing the solution I obtained the following integral to solve

$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dk \frac{k \sin(k a)}{k^2-m^2},$$
where $a$ is a positive constant.

Please help me, I am getting a result proportional to the cosine, but I need that in the limit of *a* tending to infinity my solution go to zero!